# avconv: make a video from a subset on images

Tags: ubuntu, video, avconv

I am trying to make a bunch of png's into a video using avconv, the png's are numbered like `filename_<number>` so I usually just use the command:

`avconv -r 10 -i filename_%d.png -b:v 1000k test.mp4`

I now want to make a video from a subset of the files `filename_8` - `filename_50` lets say, so I've copied these files into a new directory and tried the same command but now I get the error:

```
filename_%d.png: No such file or directory
```

I assume this is because the numbering doesn't start from 1?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
avconv -r 10 -start_number 8 -i filename_%d.png -b:v 1000k test.mp4
```

You will need a recent 9.x version of [avconv](http://libav.org/download.html) for the `-start_number` option; it is not in version 0.8.x.  Alternatively you could use a recent version of [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).  Or rename the files to start with a number between 0 and 4, as it will check for those names by default.

Comment: Note that in some versions (9.16 for me) this option is silently ignored. `avconv` does not necessarily report an error in this case, since the option can be interpreted as part of other command-line modifiers.

Comment: `avconv -r 10 -start_number 5 -i tt_img_0%04d.jpg -b:v 1000k out.mp4` doesn't work in my case: "No such file or directory", in spite of the fact that files are present starting from `tt_img_00005.jpg`.

Comment: `mencoder "mf://*.jpg" -mf fps=10 -o test.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=msmpeg4v2:vbitrate=800` does the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You can concatenate the files with cat and then use the image2pipe demuxer to read them in avconv. Like `cat filename* | avconv -f image2pipe -i - ...`

Answer (score 5):

Check this out; according to ffmpeg this is how they doing it and it works

1. First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For
   example: `img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg, ...`
2. Then you may run:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
   ```

   Notice that `%d` is replaced by the image number.

   `img%03d.jpg` means the sequence `img001.jpg`,
   `img002.jpg`, etc.
3. Use the ‘-start_number’ option to declare a starting number for the
   sequence. This is useful if your sequence does not start with
   `img001.jpg` but is still in a numerical order. The following
   example will start with `img100.jpg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 100 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
   ```
4. If you have large number of pictures to rename, you can use the
   following command to ease the burden. The command, using the bourne
   shell syntax, symbolically links all files in the current directory
   that match *jpg to the `/tmp` directory in the sequence of
   `img001.jpg`, `img002.jpg` and so on.

   ```
   x=1;  
   for i in *jpg;  
   do counter=$(printf %03d $x);  
   ln -s "$i" /tmp/img"$counter".jpg;  
   x=$(($x+1));
   ```